# Synchronizing data across threads in C with user input

Tags: c, multithreading, user-controls, mutex, race-condition

I'm building an embedded thing with some physical buttons. I've got different threads which handle different modes which the thing can be in, for example:

```
void *MakeToastThread() {
for(;;)
   if(CURRENT_MODE==MAKE_TOAST) makeSomeToast();
   else sleep(50ms);

void *MakeCoffeeThread() {
for(;;)
   if(CURRENT_MODE==MAKE_COFFEE) makeSomeCoffee();
   else sleep(50ms);

main ()
   // start threads
   // poll buttons
   // set CURRENT_MODE (global) using mutex_lock/mutex_unlock
```

Each of these threads updates a display when they are active and I'm noticing race conditions are corrupting the display. My question is **what is the best approach to avoid the different threads from updating the display at the same time?** Or more broadly, how should a C program handle user interrupts and sync data in different threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One suggestion would be to have a separate thread that is the *only* one responsible for I/O with the user.

Then have the other threads use inter-thread communications of some description if they want to interact with the user.

Many systems use this concept and it greatly eases complexity.

An example would be a message queue between a thread *wanting* I/O and the thread *doing* I/O.

For example, it could send an output request message to the responsible thread with content specifying what to print and where. Then it could just carry on, safe in the knowledge that the output would be done at some point.

Or it could send an input request detailing the prompt and where to write it, the maximum input size, the memory location where the input should be put and the address of a callback function to call, or flag to set, when the operation has ended. Complex but, as an atomic operation, something that will make users of the facility a lot happier.

---

Another possibility is to make the user I/O just another resource that each thread could lock with a mutex when it wants access to it.

The thread with the mutex is the only one allowed to interact and the others will be forced to wait until it's made available again.

However, *this* solution may end up with threads being blocked when they could otherwise be doing real work. That probably wouldn't matter for output since that should be relatively fast, but *input* may become a problem, since it relies on the user actually entering something.

Comment: thanks, this chapter on condition variables in threads was also very helpful http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-cv.pdf